# Is flutter sdk or framework ?

Tags: flutter

Is flutter SDK or Framework? I have an idea on SDK and Framework but it's mentioned as both SDK([here](https://flutter.io/)) and framework([here](https://developers.googleblog.com/2018/02/announcing-flutter-beta-1.html)) in official blogs

Answer (score 4):

Flutter includes the Dart SDK. I'd say Flutter is more a framework.
Together I'd say it's rather a platform.
All these terms aren't that well defined, therefore it's hard to give a definitive answer.

If you could explain why this differentiation is important to you, it might be easier to give a more concrete answer.

See also [Frameworks vs. SDKs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424846/frameworks-vs-sdks)

Comment: I started learning Flutter and was wondering what it really is and the extent of its usage(What it can do in future). In simple statement, if  Flutter is just a framework, it's usage is limited(than SDK's capabilities). Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Sorry, can't make sense of your comment. The problem is that "Framework" and "SDK" are vaguely specified terms. I don't know how to explain something in this terms. There isn't really a limitation of what you can do with Flutter.

Comment: "There isn't really a limitation of what you can do with Flutter". Good to know this as a beginner. Thanks.